# Fatal error on install

Tags: install

I have AMPPS installed on my Mac OS X, and am trying to install the CMS. When I browse to http://craft.dev/admin to install, it redirects to http://craft.dev/admin/install with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctype_alpha() in /Users/username/domains/craft.dev/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Lexer.php on line 380
```

Any suggestions on fixing the issue?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you don't have the php [ctype extention](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) installed or enabled.

Comment: In my phpinfo I thought it said it was enabled...it wasn't, thus the error. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad you found it. I'll add it as an answer so we can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the php ctype extension is installed or enabled.